# Monkey talk automation tool error with JS and Component Tree

Tags: javascript, automation, build-automation, android-testing

I just started write some automation scripts for my app.
On the iOS version, I use apple UIAutomation, and for the android version I started working with a nice tool called MonkeyTalk by [GorillaLogic](http://www.gorillalogic.com/) and I got some problems...

1) While I press the componentTree button, my app suddenly crashes (I also work with apple UIAutomation, it's never happened to me with this tool)

2) While I trying running a *.JS file, the IDE doesn't recognise loops.

Did anyone know how can I solve whose problems?